# Rails Script/generate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have ruby on rails installed on my ubuntu 8.10 desktop. Script/generate came up with this error.

```
# script/generate
undefined method `index' for #<Enumerator: "Rails Info:":each_line>
```

any ideas?

Thanks for you help,
zeem

Comment: Do you find which line of which line you see the "undefined method" exception? Also what's the version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Thanks for your help

ruby is 1.88
rails is 2.3.5

What do you mean exactly by finding which line? I don't see a line number in the error.

Comment: script/generate what? Is this is custom generator or are you creating a model or something simple.. can we get a little bit ore code..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried updating ruby to 1.9.1?

Comment: For sure it is not a problem with ruby version.

Comment: Strangely his advice worked.  I uninstalled gems, ruby, ect, and started by installing 1.9.1, then gems, and rails, ect. 

And it worked!

Thanks for the help. Problem resolved.